# my next "section" moves with my javascript animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a junior developer and I am coding my portfolio. I have a problem which is the following:

I put an animation effect typing on a keyboard on a "p" with JS and it moves a lot of my elements.

I managed to fix some with: "position absolute" and some CSS adjustments but the second problem is that I put a JS library to put a dark mode and "position: absolute" makes that the dark mode does not take disregard color changes.

Here is the HTML5 code:

```
<section class="landing-page">
        <p>Luck, <br> web developer <span id="monSpan">html</span> </p>  **<-- animation is here**

        <div>
            
            <img src="/img/undraw_developer_activity_re_39tg.svg" alt="">
            
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="end-landing-page">
        <div>

            <button>En savoir plus <span class="material-symbols-outlined">
                arrow_downward
                </span> </button>  **<-----the moving div is here**
        </div>
</section>
```

Here is the CSS3 code:

```
.landing-page {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.landing-page p {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  font-size: 4rem;
 
}


.landing-page img {
  height: 10em;
  padding-left: 20%;
  padding-right: 9%;
}

.landing-page div {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 40%;
}


#monSpan {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-color: rgb(129, 129, 255);
}



.end-landing-page div {
 
 padding-top: 10%;
 padding-left: 8%;

}

.end-landing-page button {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: rgb(129, 129, 255);
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  
}
```

as said before I tried with the "position" property and it works but the dark mode library no longer works on these elements

I also tried with the "z-index" property but without result

I am French and use google translation, and there may be bad translations do not hesitate to ask me to rephrase.

Comment: Also have a look at [Markdown Wikipedia FR](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) for writing SO questions.

Comment: @darvinde why this answer ?

Comment: Why? Cause it was formatted really bad. You changed it now.